# call cuda from c file - how to manipulate an argument

Tags: c, cuda

I have in a cu file :

```
__device__ float generate( curandState* globalState, int ind ) 
{
    curandState localState = globalState[ind];
    float RANDOM = curand_uniform( &localState );
    globalState[ind] = localState;
    return RANDOM;
}

__global__ void setup_kernel ( curandState * state, unsigned long seed )
{
    int id = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    curand_init ( seed, id, 0, &state[id] );
}

__global__ void kernel(float* A,float *B, curandState* globalState, int Asize,int Bsize)
{
     // generate random numbers
     for(int i=0;i<Asize;i++){
       .....
     for (int i=0 ;i<Bsize;i++){
    float k = generate(globalState, i);
    B[i]=k;
    }
}

void kernel_wrapper(float* A,float* B, curandState* globalState, int Asize ,int Bsize)
{
....
    //create random states  
    curandState* devStates;
    cudaMalloc ( &devStates, N*sizeof( curandState ) );

    // setup seeds
    setup_kernel <<< 1, N >>> ( devStates,unsigned(time(NULL)) );

    // copy arrays from host to device
    cudaMemcpy(A_dev, A_host,Asize* sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(B_dev, B_host,Bsize* sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //generate random numbers
    kernel<<<1,1>>> (A_dev,B_dev, devStates, Asize , Bsize);

    // copy result from device to host
    cudaMemcpy(A_host, A_dev,Asize* sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(B_host, B_dev,Bsize* sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
 ...
}
```

> Now ,in c code:

```
...
extern void kernel_wrapper(float* A,float* B, curandState* globalState, int Asize ,int Bsize)
....
int main()
{
...
 kernel_wrapper(&A,&B, curandState* globalState,Asize ,Bsize)
    ....
```

I am not sure what to do with the argument `curandState* globalState`.
How should I use it?
Because I am not using any

> curandState

value in c code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[assuming everything else is correct]**

it seems your kernel_wrapper doesn't need that parameter at all. The **devStates** pointer is a pointer to a seed of random values generated into the `setup_kernel()` that is later passed to `kernel()` where a distribution is applied.

Short answer: it seems from the posted code that you can safely remove that `globalState` parameter from the `kernel_wrapper`

Comment: :Yes!You are right,I didn't noticed!But ,in another case where it is necessary how can we deal with it?Do you know?Do you have any examples?Thanks!

Comment: That seems to be a seed initialized from a source. A randomness source is a generator of casual numbers (e.g. an algorithm which may draw some numbers from your mouse coordinates). The important thing is: it must be reliably random and its numbers should be hard to reproduce. Those random numbers are then "weighted" by a distribution function to obtain a probability distribution like the ones you probably studied during your academic years. I'm not familiar with that code but this process is already set and in place.

Comment: Also: in case you want to change your distribution function you should change curand_uniform to something different that suits your needs, take a look at the CURAND library http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CURAND_Library.pdf

Comment: :Ok,thank you.I have another problem if you are interested :) .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783216/call-cuda-from-c-results-in-errors