# call cuda from c results in errors

Tags: c, cuda

The errors I am receiving are:

> ‘blockIdx’ was not declared in this scope 
>   expected primary-expression before ‘<’ token
>
> expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
>
> expected primary-expression before ‘<’ token
>
> expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token

(the "<,>" refers to the kernel call <<<>>>)

Also,in main function I receive:

> error: cannot convert ‘float**’ to ‘float*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void
>   kernel_wrapper(float*, float*, int, int)

cu file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>

.....
__global__ void kernel(float* A,float *B, curandState* globalState, int Asize,int Bsize)
{
...

void kernel_wrapper(float* A_host,float* B_host, int Asize ,int Bsize)
{
...
//allocate host memory 
    A_host=(float*)malloc(Asize*sizeof(float));
    B_host=(float*)malloc(Bsize*sizeof(float));

    //allocate device memory
    float* A_dev,*B_dev;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &A_dev,Asize* sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**) &B_dev,Bsize* sizeof(float));
....

 kernel<<<1,1>>>(A_host,B_host, devStates,Asize,Bsize);
...
```

c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "solve.cu"


extern void kernel_wrapper(float* A,float* B, int Asize ,int Bsize);
...
int main()
{...
A = (float*)malloc(N*N*sizeof(float));
B = (float*)malloc(N*HS*sizeof(float));
...
kernel_wrapper(A,B,Asize ,Bsize);
...
```

I am compiling as:

```
 g++ -o mycode myfile.c -I/usr/local/cuda-5.5/include -L/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64 -lcurand -lcutil -lcudpp -lcuda -lstdc+
```

Comment: how are A and B declared? And where is blockIdx's code?

Comment: Also: g++ is for compiling c++ sources, is this C or C++?

Comment: @David Kernin :I am declaring as float* A = NULL; and same for B and then I allocate as above(A = (float*)malloc(N*N*sizeof(float));).The file is c but I use g++ to be ok with the cu file which contains iostream etc..

Comment: If that's C it should be compiled with gcc instead of g++ and you can't link against stdc++. Also compile the .cu file as Robert noted below. If it only contains cpp code, then also g++ could work.

Comment: @David Kernin:Ok,I renamed the file as cpp and when I do g++ -c -I/usr/local/cuda-5.5/include  myfile.cpp  ,it shows me all the errors as I have in the post

Comment: Don't include solve.cu in your cpp/c/whatever file, you need to compile them separately. .cu with nvcc, .c or .cpp with g++ or gcc

Comment: @David Kernin:Yes,you are right!Now,I am getting only the last error

Comment: @David Kernin:Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't include `solve.cu` which contains device code (e.g. kernels) in a `.c` file and then compile it properly with `g++`

Device code has to be compiled by `nvcc`

Instead, you will need to compile the two files separately, then link them together.

I would suggest renaming your `myfile.c` to `myfile.cpp`

Also *remove* this line from your `myfile.cpp`:

```
#include "solve.cu"
```

Then compile with:

```
nvcc -c solve.cu
g++ -c -I/usr/local/cuda-5.5/include  myfile.cpp 
g++ -o mycode solve.o myfile.o -L/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64 -lcudart -lcurand -lcutil -lcudpp -lcuda
```

For the last issue, you are passing double pointers (`**`):

```
kernel_wrapper(&A,&B,Asize ,Bsize);
```

Where the prototype is expecting single pointers (`*`):

```
extern void kernel_wrapper(float* A,float* B, int Asize ,int Bsize);
```

`A` and `B` are *already* of type `float *`, so it looks to me like you should pass them directly:

```
kernel_wrapper(A,B,Asize ,Bsize);
```

**EDIT:** Responding to a question below.

The problem is the pointers `A_host` and `B_host` (parameters to `kernel_wrapper`) are being passed *by value* to the kernel wrapper function, and the kernel wrapper function is allocating the storage for those pointers, but the newly modified pointer reflecting the allocated storage is not (cannot) be passed back to the calling function (i.e. the function that called `kernel_wrapper`).

You could allocate the storage for `A_host` and `B_host` in the calling function, and then pass the pointer (and then no need to `malloc` those pointers in `kernel_wrapper`) or you could modify the kernel wrapper as follows:

```
void kernel_wrapper(float** A_host,float** B_host, int Asize ,int Bsize)
{
...
//allocate host memory 
    *A_host=(float*)malloc(Asize*sizeof(float));
    *B_host=(float*)malloc(Bsize*sizeof(float));

    //allocate device memory
    float* A_dev,*B_dev;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &A_dev,Asize* sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**) &B_dev,Bsize* sizeof(float));
....
 cudaMemcpy(A_dev, *A_host, Asize*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMemcpy(B_dev, *B_host, Bsize*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

 kernel<<<1,1>>>(A_dev,B_dev, devStates,Asize,Bsize);
...
```

You would then also need to modify your calling line in the .cpp file:

```
int main()
{...
  float *A, *B;
  int Asize = N*N;
  int Bsize = N*NHS;
...
  kernel_wrapper(&A,&B,Asize ,Bsize);
...
```

The way your code is posted now, you are doing a `malloc` operation twice each for `A` and `B` and that is not necessary.

Comment: :When I am compiling with g++ -c -I.... myfile.cpp ,it gives me all the errors I have in my post.

Comment: Don't link against stdc++

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Ok, good point , I removed it.Now I only take the last error cannot convert ‘float**’ to ‘float*’ for argument ‘1’

Comment: I'm not writing an answer since Robert already wrote everything I had to write, it would be pointless.

Comment: That's just a basic C/C++ problem you have.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Sorry to bother you..It just seems that the values from A and B can't be passed from cu to cpp..If I print the values from cu file they are generated ok.But calling the wrapper function from cpp file results in no copying the values and they are all zero (A and B).

Comment: updated my answer.  There were additional problems in your code.

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Hello and thanks for the help.I tried using the ** reference but when I run the code ,some first elements (1 or 2) from the result matrices A and B are zero and I receive segmentation fault. If I try not to allocate A and B at the cpp file ,and leave everything as it was ,it still can't pass the values to cpp.

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Nevermind,I used cudaFreeHost instead of free and it works fine!Really mess with free!If you can tell me only how can I use the cudahostalloc in this example,because right now we have *A_host=(float*)malloc(Asize*sizeof(float));.How should I use it with hostAlloc?

Comment: Have you reviewed the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g15a3871f15f8c38f5b7190946845758c) ?

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Yes,just that I can't figure how to hostalloc the A for example.Using malloc we can do "*A_host=(float*)malloc(Asize*sizeof(float));" but using mallochost how should I write it?Like that? "cudaMallocHost((void**) &(*A_host),Asize*sizeof(float))"?Because like that I am receiving a Segmentation fault

Comment: @Robert Crovella:In other words.Using "*A_host=(float*)malloc(Asize*sizeof(float));" and "cudaFree(*A_host);" results in "invalid device pointer" , using "free(*A_host);" results in "segmentation fault" and using "cudaFreeHost(*A_host);" results in  "CUDA Error:  invalid argument"

Comment: @Robert Crovella:And I just figured that the results are ok if I not use free memory at all!

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Ok, I figured (I opened a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883040/using-free-for-the-host-results-in-segmentation-fault/21883088?noredirect=1#21883088) .Thanks and sorry for the messages.:)

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Hello,I am struggling to make this compiled under gcc but it gives me " undefined reference to `kernel_wrapper'
".I read that I shouldn't use "extern" because is for c++ compiler,so I tried to declare a "wrapper.h" where I have the declaration of the function and then include "wrapper.h" in my c file.But it doesn't work.If you know how should I do it,I 'll be grateful.And I am sorry if I am disturbing you..Thanks

Comment: If you can create a simple set of files that represent what you are trying to do, and provide the commands you are using to compile, I can probably help.  You can simply post in www.pastebin.com and link here, or post a new SO question.  There are actually many SO questions like that one already.

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Here http://pastebin.com/xNTgswPm  is the link.Thank you.(I read a lot of posts but I can't figure!).

Comment: You are still tripping over C and C++ linkage. There are plenty of SO questions about it. `nvcc` creates c++ output by default.  `gcc` when compiling a .c file creates c-style output by default.  The simplest solution is to rename your `mycfile.c` to `mycfile.cpp` and use `g++` instead.  Here's an [example](http://pastebin.com/HyvCy6yv).  In the future, please provide a *complete*, *compilable* example just as I have done.  Don't put `...` in your files or anything that doesn't compile.  Include all necessary header files and necessary variable definitions, just as I have done.  It's not hard.

Comment: [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736811/linking-c-code-with-cuda-code/13736991#13736991) an example of a similar question/answer, which links to another similar question/answer

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Ok,thank you very much for that.I didn't realize that with gcc you can't link properly cu files with c files.Thanks!