# using free for the host results in segmentation fault

Tags: c, memory, cuda

I have a cu file with the kernel like:

```
__global__ void kernel(float* A,float *B, curandState* globalState,int Asize,int Bsize)
{
   ....

}

void kernel_wrapper(float** A_host,float** B_host, int Asize ,int Bsize)
{
   ...

    //allocate host memory 
    *A_host=(float*)malloc(Asize*sizeof(float));
    *B_host=(float*)malloc(Bsize*sizeof(float));

    //allocate device memory
    float* A_dev,*B_dev;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**) &A_dev,Asize* sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**) &B_dev,Bsize* sizeof(float)));

    // copy arrays from host to device
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(A_dev, *A_host,Asize* sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(B_dev, *B_host,Bsize* sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    ....
    kernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(A_dev,B_dev, devStates,Asize,Bsize);

    // copy result from device to host
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(*A_host, A_dev,Asize* sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(*B_host, B_dev,Bsize* sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    //clean up device memory
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(A_dev));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(B_dev));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(devStates));
    //clean up host memory
    free(*A_host);
    free(*B_host);
}
```

and a cpp file from which I am calling the kernel:

```
...
extern void kernel_wrapper(float** A,float** B, int Asize ,int Bsize);
...
int main()
{
    ...
    float* A;
    float* B;
    ...
    kernel_wrapper(&A,&B,Asize ,Bsize);
    ...
    free(A);
    free(B);
```

Now,using the

```
free(*A_host);
free(*B_host);
```

in cu file results in

> Segmentation fault

If I use cudaFree or cudaFreeHost (which are not right because I am allocating with alloc) it shows "invalid device pointer" or "invalid argument".

If I will not use free at all ,the program runs fine.

Why is that and what is the appropriate process regarding these memory allocations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `free()` twice on the same pointers, that's not valid. The memory management in this code is strange and confusing.

I guess it makes the most sense to remove the `free()` calls inside the `kernel_wrapper()` function; since it's set up to return the pointers to the caller, it doesn't make sense to `free()` the memory in the function.

Comment: :So,if I was just using only the cu file I would use free there but because I am calling the kernel from another file /function ,it is better to deallocate there.And why the memory management is strange?Can you please tell me/correct me?Thanks

Comment: :Thanks for the answer.If you could give me some advice at the above comment also..